# flex command not found when installing flex

Tags: linux, makefile, redhat, flex-lexer, configure

```
tar xvjf flex-2.5.39.tar.bz2      // Uncompress the archive

cd flex-2.5.39                    // 

./configure --prefix=$HOME/flex   // ./configure

       *No errors*                //  success with no error
make                              //  run make

One thounsand lines later...      // Error
.../flex-2.5.39/missing: line 52: flex: command not found
WARNING: `flex` is missing on your system. You should only need it if you modified a `.l` ...etc
```

The error said that flex is not installed in my system !!, what I'm missing? I'm on the way to install it.
Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to include a bit more error context -- the last dozen or so lines before the `command not found` line.  Or is this really just a warning (not an error), and the build completed successfully after this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a weird one -- you shouldn't need an existing flex unless you modified scan.l prior to building it.

Check the timestamps on scan.c and scan.l and make sure scan.c exists and is newer.  If not, run

```
tar xjfv flex-2.5.39.tar.bz2 flex-2.5.39/scan.c
```

in the parent directory to reextract (just) scan.c and then rerun the make (shouldn't need to reconfigure).

Comment: Perhaps your are right. I don't what happend but when I re tar the file and do same commads, it works !. Thanks Chris

Comment: Why this question is voted down? I tried to be short and at the same time provide the necessary information

Comment: 9 month later, I re-encountered the same problem and re tar the package solves it, if someone looks for the same problem.